# How do I get a slider value in jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having trouble getting the value of a slider in jQuery Mobile. I want to be able to get the value of a slider and feed this into a calculation which will work out costs and savings etc.

My code works on a normal HTML website (link below) but I am trying to get it to work in a PhoneGap app using Jquery Mobile. **I'm actually using a Flat UI version (1.4.0) of jQuery Mobile found on GitHub, but I have also tried this using the standard 1.4.2 jQuery Mobile JS and CSS with the same outcome.**

In the app, my header looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I've been though the code and narrowed it down to an issue in jQuery Mobile JS file and CSS file:

- If I **remove the JQM JS file and keep the CSS file** it works, but obviously there's no function or styling across the app.
- If I **remove the JQM CSS file and keep the JS file** it works, but there is no styling across the app or on the slider (which shown as a number input instead).
- If I **remove both files** it works, but obliviously there's no JQM left!

This JSFiddle is a near copy of the calculator:
http://jsfiddle.net/tooze/H6FhD/

You can see a working web version of this calculator here: http://bit.ly/1lsUz8a

Have I written something incorrectly in my code? Or is it something conflicting in the JQM files?

Thank you in advance

Comment: listen to `change` event http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7rBJv/

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply! Yes that works! I did try `change` event, but must've done it a different way... obviously the wrong way.